# Connection failed: Buffer is not defined - Error when subscribing to AWS Amplify (graphql) Subscriptions after update to v4.7.0

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have just updated from Amplify-cli 4.0.0 to 4.7.0 and now I am getting these errors when attempting to listen for my subscriptions.

```
{provider: AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider, error: {…}}
provider: AWSAppSyncRealTimeProvider {_config: {…}, socketStatus: 0, keepAliveTimeout: 300000, subscriptionObserverMap: Map(0), promiseArray: Array(0), …}
error:
errors: Array(1)
0:
message: "Connection failed: Buffer is not defined"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I am using Ionic 4, and just before the update everything was working just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the below link: Looks like you need to polyfill buffer.

https://github.com/agoncal/swagger-ui-angular6/issues/2